# Что показывает Linux команда /usr/bin/time в поле maxresident?

Tags: память, linux

Linux avp-ubu1 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Казалось бы очевидно (из man)

```
          M      Maximum resident set size of the process during its life‐
                 time, in Kilobytes.
```

Однако, значение, которое я увидел для тестируемой программы, выглядело каким-то несуразно большим.

Написал простой тест, который делает `malloc(), memset()` и потом `free()` и распечатал данные по памяти из `/proc/self/status` в разных точках этой программки.

`/usr/bin/time maxresident` **оказался равен** VmHWM * 4 (???) VmHWM: Peak resident set size ("high water mark").
(См. man 5 proc). В принципе если 'kB' после значения VmHWM  это количество (в тысячах)  4Kbytes страниц, то похоже. Но (!) уж больно это VmHWM  совпадает с количеством байт выделяемых malloc.

***Что бы все это значило?***

Вывод программки

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$ gcc mem.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$ /usr/bin/time ./a.out 4000000
VmPeak:     4000 kB
VmSize:     4000 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:       508 kB
VmRSS:       508 kB
VmData:      184 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:         8 kB
VmLib:      1640 kB
VmPTE:        28 kB
start vmsize: 4000

VmPeak:     7912 kB
VmSize:     7912 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:       560 kB
VmRSS:       560 kB
VmData:     4096 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:         8 kB
VmLib:      1640 kB
VmPTE:        32 kB
malloc 4000000 vmsize: 7912

VmPeak:     7912 kB
VmSize:     7912 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:      4464 kB
VmRSS:      4464 kB
VmData:     4096 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:         8 kB
VmLib:      1640 kB
VmPTE:        36 kB
memset vmsize: 7912

VmPeak:     7912 kB
VmSize:     4004 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:      4468 kB
VmRSS:       556 kB
VmData:      188 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:         8 kB
VmLib:      1640 kB
VmPTE:        28 kB
end vmsize: 4004

0.01user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 250%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 17872maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1157minor)pagefaults 0swaps
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$
```

---

Просто обновил (через 2 недели), может быть кто-нибудь из новичков знает?

**=== UPDATE ===**

Возьмем простую программку

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char cmd[100];
  struct rusage r;
  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r);
  printf("ru_maxrss: %ld\n", r.ru_maxrss);
  sprintf(cmd, "grep Vm /proc/%d/status", (int)getpid());
  system(cmd);
  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r);
  printf("ru_maxrss: %ld\n", r.ru_maxrss);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

и запустим ее

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out
ru_maxrss: 2544
VmPeak:     2112 kB
VmSize:     2024 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:       284 kB
VmRSS:       284 kB
VmData:       32 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:         4 kB
VmLib:      1824 kB
VmPTE:        16 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
ru_maxrss: 2544
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

а теперь запустим ее же через `/usr/bin/time`

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ /usr/bin/time ./a.out
ru_maxrss: 280
VmPeak:     2112 kB
VmSize:     2024 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:       280 kB
VmRSS:       280 kB
VmData:       32 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:         4 kB
VmLib:      1824 kB
VmPTE:        16 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
ru_maxrss: 280
End
0.00user 0.02system 0:00.07elapsed 30%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 840maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+583minor)pagefaults 0swaps
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

В последнем запуске мы видим, что наш `Maximum resident set size`, полученный из `getrusage()` равен **280** и совпадает со значением VmRSS из /proc/PID/status.

**Однако, в выводе /usr/bin/time мы видим 840**. Вот и вопрос, **почему???**

Кстати, если кто-то обратил внимание, то в первом запуске getrusage() возвращает почему-то совсем другое число (не совпадающее ни с чем в /proc/PID/status ... ), но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438932/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, какой из вопросов дубликат? (мой от **2012** (3 года назад, обновлен тогда же) вопрос по Вашей ссылке -- **2015 год**). / Более того, Вы просто не осознали вопрос (видимо его смысл *слишком завуалирован*). Сейчас попробую сделать **update** и сформулировать более четко.

Comment: там ответ на вопрос, что такое resident set size. а движок не даёт указать дубликат, так как ответ там не имеет баллов.

Comment: а разница в показаниях, мне кажется, вполне очевидна: если заглянуть в исходники программы `/usr/bin/time`, то видно, что сначала происходит выполнение программы, а затем запрашивается информация об **уже** завершившемся процессе. а внутри вашего процесса запрос информации о ресурсах происходит «на пол-дороги».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, OK. Оформите как ответ.

Comment: отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ или принятым или хотя бы полезным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. что такое *maximum resident set size* — объясняется вкратце [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439855/178576).
2. разница в «показаниях» между тем, что выдаёт тестовая программа и тем, что выдаёт программа `/usr/bin/time`, запускающая тестовую программу, заключается в **моменте «снятия показаний»**:

   тестовая программа делает это **в процессе** своего выполнения, а `/usr/bin/time` — уже **после завершения** тестовой программы.

понятно, что в **разные** моменты времени динамически изменяющаяся величина, характеризующая процесс, может изменяться.

---

**обновление**

но столь кардинальное различие (в четыре раза) проистекает из ошибки в исходниках *gnu/time*.

в дистрибутиве *debian* эта ошибка была [исправлена](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=649402) коротким [патчем](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?filename=time.diff;bug=649402;msg=5;att=1):

```
--- time-1.7.orig/time.c    2011-11-20 17:48:44.000000000 +0000
+++ time-1.7/time.c 2011-11-20 17:50:25.000000000 +0000
@@ -398,7 +398,7 @@
               ptok ((UL) resp->ru.ru_ixrss) / MSEC_TO_TICKS (v));
          break;
        case 'M':       /* Maximum resident set size.  */
-         fprintf (fp, "%lu", ptok ((UL) resp->ru.ru_maxrss));
+         fprintf (fp, "%lu", (UL) resp->ru.ru_maxrss);
          break;
        case 'O':       /* Outputs.  */
          fprintf (fp, "%ld", resp->ru.ru_oublock);
```

Comment: К сожалению, неверно. Я все же переборол свою лень (чуть-чуть),  скачал сорсы GNU time version 1.7 и посмотрел сорсы ядра. / Ошибка у GNU. Они умножают полученный в wait3 RSS на pagesize (функция ptok() в time.c) / А сейчас в [Linux](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sys.c?id=HEAD) line 1613 **возвращает RSS в  килобайтах**

Comment: @avp, честно говоря, не вижу разницы. кроме той, что в исходниках *time* меняется последовательность операций деления-умножения для защиты от переполнения (я приложил фрагменты к ответу).

Comment: На входе уже число в килобайтах, потом оно увеличивается в 4 раза и возвращается. (Просто вставьте `printf(" PTOK=%ld ");` в начале функции, пересоберите  и запустите `./time -v ls`. Все станет очевидно).

Comment: понятно. в debian это давно [исправили](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=649402). а апстрим, как обычно, неспешен.

Comment: Будем надеяться (что глядя на подобные этому вопросы) и в остальных местах со временем подправят

Comment: в убунте, которой вы тогда (судя по выдаче `uname`) пользовались, надо думать, дебиановские патчи тоже давно присутствуют. я внёс коррективы в ответ.

Comment: А  вообще с RSS из getrusage() и /proc/PID/status все странно и как-то не очень понятно. Если интересно, можете поиграться с http://pastebin.com/QWQQt5m1 / Что же касается непосредственно вопроса, то видимо короткий и правильный ответ -- `значение ru_maxrss из struct rusage, полученной из wait3() (иногда с ошибкой в 4 раза)`

Comment: @avp, если я понимаю верно, то *ru_maxrss* появился сравнительно недавно: [в 2009-м](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1f10206cf8e945220f7220a809d8bfc15c21f9a5). возможно, из-за «молодости фичи» и проистекают «странности» в её использовании.

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю, может есть любители читать-менять код ядра и они все расскажут (у меня-то ведь интерес, конечно же, "чисто теоретический", вряд ли соберусь наладить всю экспедицию со сборкой-отладкой kernel)

Comment: @avp, я — точно не такой «любитель». если какой-то интерес и есть к «ядрёным потрохам», то чисто академический.