# Команда time в Linux

Tags: linux, время

Всем привет!
Я написал программу, где просто делаю

```
mas = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
for (a=0; a<N; a++) mas[a]=4095;
```

и просто в недопонимании.
`/usr/bin/time -f '%M %t %K %D %p %X' ./a.out`
При N=100000 вывод такой 3000 0 0 0 0 0 (3000 это среднее, +-150 в таком радиусе выдаёт иногда)
При N=1000000 вывод уже 17500 0 0 0 0 0
Почему так происходит? И вообще что показывает эта Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kbytes.? Максимум использования памяти, и т.д, как эта штука высчитывается вообще линкусом? Где про это можно почитать?

Comment: рекомендую начать поиск интересующей вас информации с прочтения `man time`.

Answer (score 1):

перевод основной части [этого ответа](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30941/110559) (оригинал сохранён в виде комментариев):

*resident set size* процесса — это размер той памяти, которая принадлежит ему и в настоящий момент присутствует (является резидентной) в оперативной памяти — *ram* (в реальной памяти, а не помещённая в *swap* или иным образом сделанная не-резидентной).

например, если процесс запрашивает кусок (*chunk*) памяти (скажем 100 мегабайт) и активно её использует (читает/пишет в неё), то его *resident set size* будет около 100 мегабайт (плюс накладные расходы, сегмент кода и т.п.).

если процесс перестанет использовать (но не освободит) эту память на некоторое время, ядро операционной системы может поместить часть этой памяти в *swap*, чтобы освободить место для других процессов (или для кэша). тогда *resident set size* уменьшится на ту величину, которую ядро «отправило» в *swap*.

а после того, как процесс продолжит использовать эту память, ядро «подгрузит» данные из *swap*-а и *resident set size* опять возрастёт.

---

**обновление**

также, возможно, в используемой вами неозвученной версии неозвученного дистрибутива, до сих пор не исправлена [ошибка в программе *gnu/time*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440472/178576).

Comment: Думаю, во всех Ваших объяснениях RSS будет нелишним акцентировать внимание на том, что RSS *это физические страницы* на которые ссылается процесс.  Вот [хорошая заметка об RSS](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/UnderstandingRSS) в старом и современных \*nix (по ссылке из wikipedia). Насколько помню, на русском наиболее подробно (из того, что я читал) управление памятью изложено в книге Р. Лава "Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки".

Comment: @avp, спасибо за ссылку на хорошую заметку. // повторю лишь, что я ни разу не программист, и сам как таковой код программы *linux*, равно как и тонкости его работы, меня интересуют лишь в чисто академическом плане.

Comment: Ну и хорошо. А там, глядишь, почитаете-поотвечаете, насмотритесь разных приемчиков, да и самому что-нибудь изобразить захочется...

Comment: @avp, я думаю, что написал за свою жизнь (и продолжаю писать) достаточно кода. а уж на исходники насмотрелся — вдоволь. в частности, когда над первым выпуском [«росы»](http://wiki.rosalab.ru/ru/index.php/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) работали — счёт пакетов, «воевать» с которыми ввиду их нежелания собираться в [«росовской» сборочной abf](http://www.rosalab.ru/products/rosa_abf), если мне память не изменяет, не десятками, а, скорее, сотнями исчисляется. но программистом себя всё равно не считаю.